# One service per sensor in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-service

I'm implementing an Android 7 application for collection sensor data from a smartphone (like acceleration, gyroscope and so on). Currently I have one backeground service which collects all sensor data (using `registerListener` and `onSensorChanged` for each sensor type) and stores them in a SQLite database (one table for each sensor).

Is this the right way to do it or should I create one service for each sensor? Especially when I have sampling rates of say 50 Hz for each sensor, I don't know if one service is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the right way to do it

With respect to the number of services, yes. You may have other problems, such as [not having background access to sensors on Android 9.0+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#privacy-changes-all).

> should I create one service for each sensor?

No.

> Especially when I have sampling rates of say 50 Hz for each sensor, I don't know if one service is enough.

Having more services has no impact on your ability to process 50Hz sampling rates. That is a matter of having a suitable threading model, so that any significant work with those samples is performed on a background thread (or a thread from a smallish thread pool).

Comment: By the way, if I would like to dump an input event file (/dev/input/), can I just create a thread in the same background service as mentioned above or should I create an additional service for this?

Comment: A thread started in the MainActivity or in the background service or in a second, separate background service?

Comment: @machinery: You should not need another service. You don't have access to `/dev/input` AFAIK, so the details may depend on how you are planning on your particular root framework.

Comment: I have a rooted device ;) I think on a rooted device I should have access to /dev/input. Or not?

Comment: @machinery: Then you'll need to see how your root stuff works. If you are forking a `Process` running things manually with `su` or something, a thread off of the nearest logical component (activity or an existing service) should work. If you are using some existing wrapper library that handles the threading for you when it forks a root process, then you would not need your own thread.